# Can I put onCreateOptionsMenu in another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am creating an application right now. I am a beginner, and I am anxious about my MainActivity. I believe it is too big, and that some things are not necessary to be in there. I am unsure of what I can safely use within a new activity.

One thing I want to separate is this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Is it possible to have this options menu setting (for the action bar) in a seperate class?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is a method from the `Activity` class, it is an intrinsic part of it an if you put that on a different `Activity` you won't get the result you want. Instead you will have you Main Activity with no `Menu` and you will find your `Menu` only if you inflate the second `Activity`.

In simpler words, `onCreateOptionsMenu` is linked to the `Activity` where it's declared. if you want to move methods to a different class I'd suggest to move methods that are not part of the `Activity` lifecycle

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask, is map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener part fo the activity lifecycle? (and thus unable to seperate) it is relating to the location button with the map fragment created in the onCreate. So I assume yes?

Comment: If you are using a `MapFragment`you could actually make a new class for it, have there the methods to initialize the map, set it up and update it and the just make calls from your Main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is possible, but you will still have to override the `OnCreateOptionsMenu`, so it wouldn't change much about your `Activity` size. It could make your code more easy to read, because everything is in seperate classes, but it won't make your activity less "big" in the sense of the data being used. I personally would not try to seperate the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` because it's a part of the `Activity` and you will always need to override the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` function if you want to display it. Try isolating big functions in your `Activity`, that are not `Activity` specific, so you can reuse them elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep `onCreateOptionsMenu` in another activity.

If you feel that your activity file is too big, that means your activity is doing things that it is not supposed to do.

Try to strip down excess code from activity into `Utilities` and `Helper` classes.